# Multiple count in single statement (esper epl)

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing, epl

I am trying to create an epl statement using esper for monitoring response times, something like this:

```
SELECT QUEUENAME, count(latency>1000) AS NUMBER_OF_SLA_BREACHES, COUNT(latency) AS TOTALS FROM ResponseWindow GROUP BY QUEUENAME
```

.. however the two count() gives same results, which is incorrect.
Thanks for any help correcting this query!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the filter as a second parameter to the `count` aggregation function like this:

```
SELECT QUEUENAME, count(*,latency>1000) AS NUMBER_OF_SLA_BREACHES, COUNT(latency) AS TOTALS FROM ResponseWindow GROUP BY QUEUENAME
```